# Android Studio 3.2.1 Gradle Build Fail (colors.xml: "Content is not allowed in prolog")

Tags: android-studio

When I am trying to create a new project in Android Studio 3.2.1, the gradle build is failing.
As per the console the reason is :

```
C:\Users\Ritangshu\AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

This thing once happened some days before but the next day it was working as expected. Yesterday, I found the problem has occurred again.

I have tried uninstalling Android Studio V3.2.1 and reinstalling it, but the issue hasn't been solved...

Comment: What is the content of `colors.xml`, the first few lines specifically?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i could fix it by deleting three folders and restarting my android studio

C:\Users\(name of your account)\.AndroidStudio3.3

C:\Users\(name of your account)\.android

C:\Users\(name of your account)\AndroidStudioProjects

wish it would be helpful

Comment: This is likely to cause other problems, such as data loss. Explaining what this may affect would make your answer much better.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Android Studio (3.5.3) and creating my first Hello Android project, things were smooth and the app ran perfectly fine and I was able to make modification and view them on the Emulator.

However, after few days, I decided to create a new module under the same project or even tried to create a new Android project, I started facing the same issue as yours where it was showing that “Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.” and it was pointing to colors.xml. Nevertheless, when I ran Gradle analysis (Gradle Scripts --> Analyze --> Inspect Code) it showed that most *.xml files in the new project are having same issue. If you open the xml files, it will look sort of corrupted but for some reason, the code got encrypted.

The workaround that really worked for me was replacing the corrupted/encrypted code with the one that I had from my first working project. I build the app and it runs perfectly fine.

The xml files that I  had to revisit were:

```
- colors.xml
- ic_launcher_foreground.xml
- ic_launcher_background.xml
- ic_launcher_round.xml
- ic_launcher.xml
```

This might not be the best solution, but it really worked out for me